# Does a copy from local directory to HDFS run a mapreduce job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When we issue a `hdfs` put or `copyfromlocal` command, does it invoke a `mapreduce` job? 
If yes, how many mappers are run? 
If not, how the transfer is done?

I read Anatomy of file read in *Hadoop-The definitive guide* but would like to get more insights on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copying local files to HDFS is done using the mapreduce job when we use put and copyFromLocal commands. Where it is actually done using **Streaming** by the hadoop client binary itself using the client libraries and queues.

While copying the contents to HDFS, the hadoop/hdfs binary command makes use of the `DistributedFileSystem` class to interact with the Name node to verify and to make an entry in the namespace about the file being copied.

Then the client uses the `DFSOutputStream` class to convert the data into packets and places the in the internal `data queue.`

The `DataStreamer` class will consume the queue contents. Also the `DataStreamer` class consults with the Namenode to assign the list of the data nodes (including the replications) and and these list of data nodes forms a `data pipe line`.

The  `DataStreamer` class only sends the packets through Streaming to the first node in the data pipeline and the on completion the first node cascades to the next node and the same process is continued until the last node in the pipeline.

I would suggest you to go through the **Anatomy of a File Write** chapter from the definitive guide book.

Comment: I read  Anatomy of file write in definitive guide well before posting this question. One thing i would like to understand is that how many maps would be used for a write is it same as that of a MR paradigm where for each split a map runs or a different paradigm. I am not able to get the info from the definitive guide.

Comment: the copy task will not be done by MR job at all.It is completely a streaming job, no mappers are involved.Its all between the hadoop client and hdfs where the mode used is Streaming only, no mappers involved. Kindly accept the answer if it is helpful

Comment: What happens in the case of `copyToLocal`?